# How to check a website if it can act as HTTP proxy server or not?

Tags: proxy, webserver, http-proxy, proxy-server

So, I need HTTP proxy server for  HTTP Connect tunneling.

How to check a website if it can act as a HTTP proxy server or not ? Do websites have to implement proxy server functionality themselves so that one can use the website as a proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check a website if it can act as a HTTP proxy server or not?

I am assuming you mean a forward (anonymous) proxy.

As indicated in [this Apache article on proxy abuse](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse), typically you would configure your browser to use the remote web server as its default proxy. The other option is to use something like telnet to test the connection e.g.:

```
telnet yoursite.example.com 80
GET http://www.yahoo.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yahoo.com
```

If you do not get the requested content (e.g. *yahoo.com*), that server likely cannot be used to proxy requests.

> Do websites have to implement proxy server functionality themselves so that one can use the website as a proxy server?

This is generally the case, yes.

Sometimes misconfiguration or security vulnerabilities can lead to cases where  the site can be (improperly) used to forward random requests, but most websites take measures against this kind of abuse.

Comment: can I also use the same procedures to check ngnix http proxy servers ? and how can anybody find those misconfiguration vulnerabilities ? are there any tools ?

Comment: Yes, the above should work for any http server. Regarding vulnerabilities and tools, Kali Linux may be of interest and Nikto (which comes pre-installed) in particular. There are also stand-alone vulnerability scanners/frameworks such as Nessus and Metasploit which can do web-related testing. All of these are intended for a wide variety of vulnerability scans, however, so you may find them a bit of overkill. A simple automated script is likely enough just to test for HTTP proxies. There are also proxy lists compiled by others, which may save time. Google is your friend.

Comment: Just as a minor FYI, looking over your questions, you may wish to consider posting on [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). They typically handle the types of things your asking about (which may net you better answers overall).

Comment: You have given very informative answers.Thank you very much 

Comment: Your very welcome. =)